# Javascript, cannot complete this action

Tags: document-library, permissions, javascript, security

i am currently running some code on a sharepoint front end and am getting this error

```
"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException"
"Cannot complete this action.\n\nPlease try again."
```

So i looked into this and it seems its because i dont have the right permissions on the list. But when i check the permissions i have Full control.

What am trying to achieve is actually simple, get a list of documents inside a specific folder in a Document library.

I dunno have any permissions on the Document library but i have full control on some folders inside that Document library.

Here is the code am using.

```
function RenommerDossier(Foldername) {


    var myQueryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Foldername + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query>";
    var MyUsername = 'Steve'
    myDocLibrary = GetListByname("Documents des juges");//my custom function, works good

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

    query.set_viewXml(myQueryString);
    var stringFullFolderUrl = 'MyDocumentLibrary/' + MyUsername + '/' + Foldername;
    query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(stringFullFolderUrl);



    myFolders = myDocLibrary.getItems(query);

    context.load(myFolders);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadBibliothequeDossierSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailedLoadDossier)
     );
}
```

If anyone could help i would be glad, thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for starters, while reading your code, I just noticed that your caml query does not have a closing </View> tag.

it should be like this:

```
var myQueryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Foldername + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
```

See if it works out. Also, it would be great if you could post the code for `GetListByName()` function.